# How can I properly send a double array in C# to a C dll?

Tags: c#, c, dll, intptr

I have a C DLL that im calling from a C# application. I am able to successfully receive the struct from the DLL but im having trouble *sending* the same struct with data into the DLL. Here is what I have:

**C# application struct:**

```
public class MatrixClass
{

    private double[,] cells;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Matrix
    {
        public IntPtr cells;
        public int cellRows;
        public int cellColumns;   
    }
}
```

**C DLL struct:**

```
    typedef struct
    {
        double **cells;
        int cellRows;
        int cellColumns;
    } Matrix;
```

Here is an example function from My C DLL that I need to recieve the struct from:

```
void GetMatrixCell(Matrix *MatrixIn, int nRow, int nColumn, double *value)
{
    *value = 0.0;
    int nColIndex = nColumn - 1;
    int nRowIndex = nRow - 1;
    *value = MatrixIn->cells[nRowIndex][nColIndex];
}
```

How im calling it:

```
[DllImport(matrixDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int GetMatrixCell(Matrix mIn, int nRow, int 
nColumn, ref double value);

public double GetCell(int Row, int Column)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    int stride = Rows * sizeof(double);
    IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Rows * stride);
    Matrix mIn = MatrixtoDLL(this, Rows, Columns, p, stride); //this = MatrixClass
    GetMatrixCell(mIn, Row, Column, ref result);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
    return result;
}
```

**MatrixtoDll Funtion from above:**

```
    public static Matrix MatrixtoDLL(MatrixClass input, int rows, int columns, IntPtr p, int stride)
    {
        Matrix toReturn = new Matrix ();
        toReturn.cellColumns = columns;
        toReturn.cellRows = rows;

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) //rows
        {
            double[] temp = new double[rows];

            for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
                temp[x] = input.cells[i, x]; //[columns, rows]

            Marshal.Copy(temp, 0, p + stride * i, rows);
        }

        toReturn.cells = p;

        return toReturn;
    }
```

Im thinking my MatrixtoDLL is where I need to rethink? or I need to be sending the data another way. Like I mentioned above I can successfully receive the data (cells) as an IntPtr and convert it to a 2d array but the program does not like they way im trying to send the struct. Thanks in advance!

Edit: This is the unhandled exception I get: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: `double **cells` is not a pointer to two-dimensional `double` array, it's a pointer to a pointer to a `double`. And your PInvoke definition does not match your C function, which is `void`. What is the value in `$exception.InnerException`?

Comment: @Charlieface my GetCell does return a the result variable, sorry for forgetting that. And There is no other info for the exception that I see other than what I pasted there

Comment: Should be `static extern void GetMatrixCell(in Matrix mIn, int nRow, int nColumn, ref double value);` and as I said, your marshaling is wrong. Your C code expects an array of pointers to single-dimension arrays.

Comment: Usually, a `double* array` argument is passed as `ref array[0]`. I think the same applies to a 2d array also, use `f(ref array[0,0])`.

Answer (score -1):

**Your P/Invoke function is not defined correctly. It shoud be**

```cs
[DllImport(matrixDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void GetMatrixCell(in Matrix mIn, int nRow, int nColumn, ref double value);
```

---

**Furthermore, `Matrix.cells` should be a pointer to an array of pointers to one-dimensional arrays, in other words a jagged array.**

We can use `GCHandle` for this, this also avoids unnecessary copying

```cs
    private double[][] cells;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Matrix
    {
        public IntPtr[] cells;
        public int cellRows;
        public int cellColumns;   
    }

public double GetCell(int Row, int Column)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    Matrix mIn = new Matrix
    {
        cellColumns = Columns,
        cellRows = Rows,
    };

    var handles = new GCHandle[this.cells.Length];

    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.cells.Length; i++)
            handles[i] = GCHandle.Alloc(this.cells[i], GCHandleType.Pinned);

        mIn.cells = handles.Select(h => h.AddrOfPinnedObject()).ToArray();
        GetMatrixCell(mIn, Row, Column, ref result);
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var h in handles)
            if(h.IsAlllocated)
                h.Free();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I must say, I'm unclear the point of `Matrix.cellColumns` and `cellRows`. The C function doesn't seem to use it.